# What does "off" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

And he was **off**, describing all about the four balls and the positions of the seven players

Comment: Too little context to say for sure, but it MAY mean that he began describing the balls and players' positions.

Comment: 'He was off' can just mean 'He started', but there is also at least a strong suggestion here of the sense that @McMahon describes, starting on an empassioned diatribe. "Don't set him off!"

Comment: Could also mean he was _off on a tangent_.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it could mean *off* in the sense of, *off to the races*. Enraptured by his own discourse and presumed passion of the sport. [*...and they're off!* A popular phrase of classic race callers. Example at about 00:06 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74Usj3K4oZ0]